# IBM EXP3000 SAS rack

Tags: ibm, sas

A couple of weeks ago one of my EXP3000 SAS Racks was not found by the server. Also, all the  Amber fault LED lit, on every disk.

Today, this also happened on my other EXP3000 after a reboot - Could it be the battery? Does it need to be replaced?

Answer (score 1):

You would examine the event log for the storage subsystem to find out.

Comment: Ok, thanks, where do I find it?

Comment: Consult the documentation for the EXP3000 boxes ? I have no idea how your environment is set up.